# SRV record does not work, doesn't redirect to another port

Tags: domain, http, redirect

These are my SRV host details:

```
HOST: _http._tcp.ngxdev.com
ANSWER: 0 29080 ngxdev.com
```

As you can see, if I enter a full link:
http:// ngxdev.com:29080(Not allowed to post more than 1 link), it works, but http://ngxdev.com does not redirect to port 29080 as it should, redirects to port 80 instead.

Using name.com, config line: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpkp0.png)

Comment: Check the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records). Browsers don't use SVR records. You will need a http server listening on 80 and redirecting or proxying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records). Browsers don't use SVR records. You will need a http server listening on 80 and redirecting or proxying.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll just make a node.js app that reads the window, if its ngxdev redirect to port... I guess?

Comment: It is sad it isn't supported yet. SRV records could be so convenient...